# Differences between returning an object vs a function in a directive definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the functional difference between the following code (in Widget Uno) using a *directive definition object* (I think it's called..?)...

```
angular.module("app").
    directive("widgetUno", ["$http", function ($http) {
        return {
                // A whole bunch of crap going on here
            },
            templateUrl: "widgetUno.html"
        };
    }]);
```

...And this code in Widget Dos?

```
angular.module("app").directive('widgetDos', function($http) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // A whole bunch of crap going on here
    };
});
```

I'm trying to convert a directive that's like Widget Uno into Widget Dos, but where do I reference the templateUrl? Is this possible in Widget Dos?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Returning only a function in a directive is just a shorthand for the `link` function in the full definition.

If you are specifying something *other than* a `link` function (like `templateUrl`) then you need to write it the long way:

```
angular.module("app").
    directive("widgetUno", ["$http", function ($http) {
        return {
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             // A whole bunch of crap going on here
          },
          templateUrl: "widgetUno.html"
        };
    }]);
```

This difference is actually documented here - http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 9):

The one returning the function is actually the shortcut for:

```
angular.module("app").directive('widgetDos', function($http) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //...
        };
    }
});
```

Use it in case your directive doesn't need template, controller etc. Other than that, there's absolutely no functional difference between those two calling approaches.

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this:

```
angular.module("app").directive('widgetDos', function($http) {
    return {
        templateUrl: "....",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // A whole bunch of crap going on here
        };
    }
});
```

See also http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (long version). There is an example.